# after I installed apache ofBiz ERP to use it in my computer I found this error on cmd

Tags: ant, open-source, erp, ofbiz

and this is my command on cmd:

C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\apache-ofbiz-18.12.06>ant run-install

Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

Answer (score 0):

What version of OFBiz are you using? Since 16.12 we no longer use Ant but Gradle. Have a look at the main README file (different suffixes are possible depending on version)